# Net Core - Add HttpClient fails with constructor error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

so I am trying to go from this:

```
services.AddScoped<IPersonAdapter>(sp =>
{
    var random1 = DoSomething1();
    var random2 = DoSomething2();
    var random3 = DoSomething3();
    
    return new PersonAdapter(random1, random2, random3);
});
```

To this:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<IPersonAdapter, PersonAdapter>(config =>
        config.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://disclosedAdress/"))
    .AddPolicyHandler(basicCircuitBreakerPolicy);
```

Whenever I try to run my API method, I get this error:

> A suitable constructor for type 'Adapters.PersonAdapter' could
> not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are
> registered for all parameters of a public constructor

This is the Adapters.PersonAdapter constructor:

```
private readonly IPersonWs client;
private readonly ILogger<PersonAdapter> logger;
    
private string Token { get; }
    
public PersonAdapter(
    IPersonWs client,
    string token,
    ILogger<PersonAdapter> logger)
{
    this.client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    Token = token ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(token));
    this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}
```

I tried adding the PersonWs that is in the constructor before Adding the HttpClient, like so:

```
services.AddTransient<IPersonWs, PersonWs>();
```

Note that PersonWS is a nuget that I am consuming.
When I do the above I get the following error:

> 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: PersonWS.IPersonWS
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: PersonWS.PersonWS': No
> constructor for type PersonWS.PersonWS' can be instantiated using
> services from the service container and default values

This is what I tried to do to achieve my AddHttpClient.
Can you guys tell me what I did wrong and what would you guys do to implement AddHttpClient?
I am doing this because I want to implement circuit breaker in te application that I'm working with, and with the services scopped, I can't really use the AddPolicyHandler on them.

If this looks confusing, please, ask me for more info, I tried making it as simple as possible for you guys.

Comment: `AddHttpClient` is being added as client but has no dependency on `HttpClient`? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, @Nkosi right, you should add `HttpClient` dependency in ctor.  Such this `public PersonAdapter(HttpClient httpClient, IPersonWs client, string token, ILogger<PersonAdapter> logger)`

Comment: I got this today, but my constructer only has ILogger.  So maybe it's the same?  I've tried adding `services.AddLogging();` prior to attempting to register my class, but it didn't help.  Curious to the answer on this one.

Comment: Well my issue happened to be that I forgot to make my class constructor public, but looks like you already have that.  So my theory above is probably nothing.